# How to solve UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in NodeJS testing framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, nightwatch.js

I'm using custom commands in my testing framework based on `Nightwatch.js`. I want to do a PUT request via `superagent`. This os my custom command:

```
const superagent = require("superagent");

exports.command = function(url, header, body, callback) {
  return superagent
    .put(url)
    .send(body) // sends a JSON post body
    .set(header)
    .then(result => {
      callback(true, result);
      return this;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err) {
        callback(false, err);
        return this;
      }
    });
};
```

And this command I'm using in my tests:

```
return client
  .apiPut(apiUrl, header, body, function(status, result) {
    assert.isTrue(status, "response status is false");
    assert.isTrue(result.ok, "response result is NOT ok");
  })
```

If everything is fine with the PUT request (`status == true` and successful response) then everything is fine and the test will finish, but if the PUT request is not successful (`status != true` and an error as result) I'm getting the following error message and the current Node process does not finish:

```
09:11:12 (node:103) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError: response status is false: expected false to be true
09:11:12     at /var/jenkins_home/jobs/MYJOB/workspace/testautomation/end2end-web-tests/pageobjects/MyPageView.js:59:20
09:11:12     at superagent.put.send.set.then.catch.err (/var/jenkins_home/jobs/MYJOB/workspace/testautomation/end2end-web-tests/commands/apiPut.js:14:9)
09:11:12     at <anonymous>
09:11:12     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
09:11:12 (node:103) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
09:11:12 (node:103) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

But I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the callback in my custom command. What should I do to solve that issue?

Comment: What testing framework are you using and how does it support asynchronous test cases?

Comment: My framework based on `Nightwatch-Cucumber` which bases on `Nightwatch.js`. It allows async await: http://mucsi96.github.io/nightwatch-cucumber/

Comment: And are you using that to wait for the promise that `command` returns?

Comment: actually I don't use awaits and async as my code shows. should I do it? I'm not an absolutely javascript programmer ;)

Comment: Yes, I guess you should. And avoid passing a callback.

Comment: maybe you can give a little example what you mean with "avoid passing a callback"?

Comment: When using promises (with `.then` syntax or with `await`  syntax) you can just return the promise from your function. It does not need to take a callback - the caller just will wait for the result of the promise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Now it is running. I've replaced the promise and replaced it completely with callbacks. Now it is working :)

```
const superagent = require("superagent");

exports.command = function(url, header, body, callback) {
  return superagent
    .put(url)
    .send(body) // sends a JSON post body
    .set(header)
    .end((error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        callback(false, result, error);
      } else {
        callback(true, result, error);
      }
    });
};
```